# Calculate sum in View of ISO-style timestamps

Tags: views, entities

I have a text field on a node type, which the user fills out with a video duration in ISO format (no validation or anything). So, '4:33' or '04:33' would be likely values for this field.

The client now needs a View which shows all these videos' titles and durations, and adds up the durations. I've looked at solutions like [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc/) and have had no real success. I've also have bad luck formatting the duration as  a datestamp and trying to manipulate it that way. I need a way to show something like this:

```
+----------+--------------+
|TITLE     | Duration     |
+----------+--------------+
|Swimming  | 4:33         |
|Diving    | 2:42         |
|Running   | 1:27         |
+----------+--------------+
|TOTAL     | 8:42         |
+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: What do you need the totals for? Will you be using them for filtering, ordering, or as an argument? Or is it just the case that when you display the times, you also want to display the total?

Comment: Just display, at least for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho your two best bets would be to either create a [custom formatter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7), or to use [`hook_field_attach_view_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_view_alter/7) to modify the display ([this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/38624/633) might help if you go down that road). I'd be happy to expand on either of those methods.

Is there any reason you're using a text field? I would've thought a dedicated duration field would've been the way to go. I've never used any myself, but Google suggests: [HMS Field](http://drupal.org/project/hms_field), [Time Period](http://drupal.org/project/timeperiod). Have you had a look at them? They might already have a formatter that supports what you want (a longshot, perhaps!).

Comment: The text field is already there, so changing it would involve losing information from at least 200 records.

Comment: Didn't realise it would require migration. It's not necessarily worth it, but in these situations in the past I've found a quick custom action coupled with Views Bulk Operations can be a surprisingly easy way to migrate data from one field type to another. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a custom view tpl in your theme . To add time using php may be this [link](http://www.openscriptsolution.com/2009/10/14/sum-time-with-format-hh-mm-ss-by-using-php/) will help

Comment: That's not the hard part. The $row variable contains only already-rendered HTML. So how do I get all the values of the fields to do the math on?

Comment: something like this 
`$i = 0;
foreach($rows as $row){
  $i = $row[XXXXX] + $i;
}`

Comment: That would work great if $row didn't contain one huge string that is the whole view as HTML already rendered.

Comment: you can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) :) `strip_tags($row)`

Comment: But it doesn't *just* contain tags, the whole content of the View is in there, tags, text, and all. For more than one row of data.